# How do you solve this differential equation by changing the dependent variable $y$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$$(1+y^2)=(\arctan(y)-x)\frac{dy} {dx}$$
The hint says to use $u=\arctan(y)$.
My working out so far is:
$$y=\tan(u) \implies \frac{dy} {dx}=\sec^2(u)\frac{du} {dx}\\ \text{Substituting: }\; 1+\tan^2 (u)=(u-x)\sec^2 (u)\frac{du} {dx}\\
\sec^2 (u)=(u-x)\sec^2 (u)\frac{du} {dx}\\
1=(u-x)\frac{du} {dx}.$$
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about initial conditions?

Comment: No initial conditions were given.

Comment: the solution containes the Product-Logarithmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuma u(x) is an invertible function, and set x(u) as the inverse. Then

$\frac{dx}{du} = x' = u-x$

$\implies x' + x = u$

Homogenious solution is $x_h = c.e^{-u}$, c any constant depending on initial condition.

The particular solution is $x_p(u) = au + b \implies a+ au + b = u \implies a =1, b=-1 \implies x_p(u) = u-1$.

Then $x(u) = c.e^{-u} + u - 1$.

Rewrite $u = arctan(y)$.

That far I could come up without knowing about $c.$

Answer (score 1):

*With the hint*:
Using your approach, we had $$1=(u-x)\frac{du}{dx}$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{du}=u-x$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{du}+x=u$$
Can you see a linear DE?

*Without the hint*:

Note that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1+y^2}{\tan^{-1}y-x}$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\tan^{-1}y-x}{1+y^2}$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{dy} + \frac{x}{1+y^2}= \frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}$$
This is a linear DE, where integrating factor is $e^{\tan^{-1}y}$,
$$\implies \frac{d}{dy}(xe^{\tan^{-1}y})=e^{\tan^{-1}y}\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}$$
$$\implies xe^{\tan^{-1}y}= \int e^{\tan^{-1}y}\frac{\tan^{-1}y}{1+y^2}dy$$
Taking $\tan^{-1}y = t$ for the integration, we get:
$$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=\int te^tdt$$
Applying by parts,
$$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=te^t-e^t+C$$
And hence,
$$xe^{\tan^{-1}y}=\tan^{-1}y(e^{\tan^{-1}y}-1)+C$$
$$\implies x=\tan^{-1}y(1-e^{-\tan^{-1}y})+Ce^{-\tan^{-1}y}$$

Comment: @corbah haha thanks!